# MarkLogic - Is it possible to configure Weekly scheduler which runs every minute until the job completes

Tags: marklogic

We are using MarkLogic v9.0-10.4

We have created 6 schedulers (one for each node, 6 node cluster) which runs every 1 minute and deletes versioned documents in batches. One batch is of 20000 docs. Which means it deletes 120k documents every minute.

Now we want again to schedule this activity on weekly basis. let's say at 9 AM. So, every week on Saturday at 9 AM these 6 schedulers should run every 1 minute until there are versioned document. (Usually, the schedulers take 5-7 minutes to delete the versioned documents)

Comment: What about having a Weekly scheduled task that is initiated at 9am, it selects all of the versions URIs and then spawns the execution of a function with those URIs that deletes the first batch. If you care about the interval it could sleep for a minute. Then if there are remaining URIs to delete, it spawns another task with the remaining URIs. When it runs out of URIs, it stops spawning more work.

Comment: I tried this way, got all the versioned uris (5 million), created batches, one batch of 10k uris, now I am passing these 10k uris to a function which deletes them. put the function call in the xdmp:spawn-function but it seems like it's running sequently, I don't see the queue size getting increased

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a module such as this installed with the URI `/tasks/delete-versions.xqy`:

```
declare variable $URIS external;
declare variable $BATCH-SIZE external;
declare variable $SLEEP external := 1000;
declare variable $MODULES-DB external;

let $head := fn:subsequence($URIS, 1, $BATCH-SIZE)
let $tail := fn:subsequence($URIS, $BATCH-SIZE + 1)
return (
  xdmp:log("deleting " || count($head) || " of " || count($URIS)),
  for $uri in $head  
  return xdmp:document-delete($uri),
  
  if (count($tail) gt 0) then 
    let $params := map:map() 
      => map:with(xs:QName("URIS") => xdmp:key-from-QName(), $tail) 
      => map:with(xs:QName("BATCH-SIZE") => xdmp:key-from-QName(), $BATCH-SIZE)
      => map:with(xs:QName("SLEEP") => xdmp:key-from-QName(), $SLEEP)
      => map:with(xs:QName("MODULES-DB") => xdmp:key-from-QName(), $MODULES-DB)
    let $options := map:map() => map:with("modules", $MODULES-DB)
    return 
      (xdmp:sleep($SLEEP), xdmp:spawn("/tasks/delete-versions.xqy", $params, $options))
  else ()
)
```

You could create a scheduled task as follows that is scheduled weekly, replacing the URIs query with your logic to select the versions to be deleted, and specifying the Modules database that the recursive delete module is installed:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
let $uris := cts:uris("", (), cts:true-query())
let $modules-db := xdmp:modules-database()
return
  xdmp:spawn("/tasks/delete-versions.xqy", 
    map:map() 
      => map:with(xs:QName("URIS") => xdmp:key-from-QName(), $uris)
      => map:with(xs:QName("BATCH-SIZE") => xdmp:key-from-QName(), 20000)
      => map:with(xs:QName("SLEEP") => xdmp:key-from-QName(), 60000)
      => map:with(xs:QName("MODULES-DB") => xdmp:key-from-QName(), $modules-db),
    map:map() => map:with("modules", $modules-db)  
  )
```